# Where are lucene RAMDirectory benchmarks and how to benchmark

Tags: lucene, benchmarking, ramdirectory

I am hoping someone can point to on how to benchmark my lucense RAMDirectory index?

I have about 300-500K documents indexed (less than 80 characters per document) and I want to benchmark how fast the in-memory RAMDirectory is.

At a very high level, should this be tens or hundreds of queries per second?

Answer (score 0):

Too many variables to even guess. What kind of queries you're running, your hardware, the makeup of your index,  etc. That can make orders of magnitude of difference, so even a high-level guess would be meaningless.

You can take a look at [Lucene's nightly benchmarks](https://home.apache.org/~mikemccand/lucenebench/) though, which use the Wikipedia English export (a much larger dataset than yours, of course, but it's something).

Comment: In that benchmark, the exact match is only 5 queries/second?  Am I reading that correctly?    What is a term query which is 40 q/s?

Comment: [TermQuery](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/TermQuery.html)